# Error in using methods in java

Tags: java

I'm still a beginner to using methods in java. I want to print the following series in java using methods.

```
1 + (1+2)/2! + (1+2+3)/3!.....n terms
```

I have done this much. I want to know why I'm not able to use `s` in `sum2` method.

```
public class SERIES {
  int factorial(int n) {
    int res = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
      res *= i;
    return res;
  }

  int sum1(int n) {
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      s += i;
    return s;
  }

  double sum2(int n) {
    double ts = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      ts = s / res;
    }
    return ts;
  }

  void main(int a) {
    int d = sum2(a);
    System.out.println(d);
  }

}
```

Comment: `s` is not declared in `sum2()`.

Comment: i did not understand....can u please explain

Comment: Either call sum1(n) in sum2() or declare s as global variable

Comment: Scope matters. You declared the variable in the method `sum1()` which is local to that method only. If you want to use across methods, move that to top (*instance level*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

declare `s` and `res` as class attributes and them will be accessible from ALL methods of your class, also you must change the main and create a double variable, because `sum2()` method returns a double.

```
public class SERIES {
    // s and res are accessible in everywhere in SERIES class.
    int s = 0;
    int res = 1;

    int factorial(int n) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            res *= i;
        return res;
    }

    int sum1(int n) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            s += i;
        return s;
    }

    double sum2(int n) {
        double ts = 0.0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            ts = s / res;
        }
        return ts;
    }

    void main(int a) {
        double d = sum2(a);   // change to double
        System.out.println(d);
    }

}
```

Comment: but when I give 'a' as 1, it gives 0.0 whereas it should give 1.

Comment: @thenewbie That's because in this code, `s` is globally declared as 0. Zero divided by anything will always be zero.

Comment: how do i use 's' and 'res' in 'sum2'?

Answer (score 2):

You should clearly understand the difference between local and global variables.

Basically, what you're declaring inside the `{ }` is a local variable. It is only accessible inside that block. So when in function `double sum2(int n)` you're trying to access variables **`s`** and **`res`** they are just not known to that function.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no `s` in the `sum2` method.  It's in the `sum1` method.  And a variable declared within a given scope only exists within that scope.

So either `sum2` needs to create such a variable:

```
double sum2(int n)
{
    double s = 1.0;
    double res = 1.0;

    double ts = 0.0;
    for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        ts = s/res;
    }
    return ts;
}
```

or it needs to accept that variable as a parameter to the method:

```
double sum2(int n, double s, double res)
{
    double ts = 0.0;
    for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        ts = s/res;
    }
    return ts;
}
```

(in which case any code which calls `sum2()` will need to pass it those values)

Conversely, you can increase the scope.  If the entire object should know of `s` then make it a class-level variable:

```
public class SERIES {
    double s = 1.0;

    // now any method in this class can access the same instance of s
}
```